# Lagrangian multipliers in the dual of semidefinite programs

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, semidefinite-programming

I have been reading about semidefinite programs and I feel completely lost as to what is going on. The lagrangian multipliers for linear, geometric and second order cone programs can be expressed as a scalar, multiplied with each constraint, or a dot product between a lagrangian vector and all the constraints $Ax - b$. And I understand this perfectly because a positive lagrangian for a $\le$ inequality constraint results in a higher value if the constraints are violated (since we are trying to minimize).

[image]

**Question:** In semidefinite programs, why are the lagrangian multipliers a matrix ? And is it also symmetric / psd ? I understand that for a SDP, the inequality constraint needs to be positive semidefinite but I don't understand how multiplying the constraints with a lagrangian-matrix *encodes* this constraint like in a LP, GP, SOCP. Im pretty sure im lacking some basic knowledge because I have 0 clue as to what is going on here.

Below is an example of a SDP whose dual is shown here https://neos-guide.org/content/semidefinite-programming. I have been trying to derive that but I don't know where to start.

[image]

Here is another example that I can't follow.

[image]

Comment: Example 2.24 of the book will help.

Comment: It is convenient to think that the Lagrange multiplier of a conic constraint should belong to the dual cone (whether it is SOCP, PSD or any other cone). And the cone $S^n$ of PSD matrices is self-dual.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you !

Comment: See also Section 5.9 and Example 5.11 in [the book by Boyd and Vandenberghe on Convex Optimisation](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)